# get posts that I have commented on with new comments?

Tags: mysql, sql, feed

I have a typical MySQL database set up for this: post table, user table, comment table.

What is the best way to query something like "Get posts where I commented that have new comments since my last comment"? I'm having trouble arriving out how to merge the other users comment_timestamp being greater than my comment_timestamp condition into the query below:

I have roughly

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE posts.id IN 
( SELECT DISTINCT posts.id FROM posts,users,comments WHERE comments.post_id = post.id AND comments.user_id = $current_user_id ) AND .. something to filter only comments where timestamp is greater than mine
```

I realize I could loop through one set and filter outside of MySQL, but I'd prefer to have it all done in MySQL if possible. I know there's probably a better way to do this with a join, but I'm lost on how to move the comment_timestamp for "my" last comment amongst both parts of the join

```
user table
-----
id

posts table
------
id
user_id

comments table
-------
id
user_id
post_id
comment_timestamp
```

Comment: please provide some data in your question .

Comment: input as well as out put data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN comments c
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE c.comment_timestamp > (
   SELECT MAX(c2.comment_timestamp)
   FROM comments c2
   WHERE c2.post_id = c.post_id
   AND c2.user_id = $current_user_id
)
```

Select post data for each post that has a comment created by a different user with a timestamp value greater than the most recent comment made by the current user. Distinct is included to only get each post once, as a post may have multiple comments after the current user's latest.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55d8d/1/0) The fiddle assumes that the current user's ID is 100 and provides the following sample cases:

- A post where the most recent comment is the current user's and other users have previously commented
- A post where the current user has commented and other users have commented afterwards
- A post where the current user has not commented but others have
- A post with no comments
- A post with only comments from the current user